# Java - Linux permissions and users

Tags: java, linux

I'm creating a application in Java which needs to create, update and read configuration/definition files. but when I run that application in Linux I can't use those files.

So I thought that I could create a "System user" for my Java app, so I can read and write those files. And not just writing the files, they would be protected in a better way.

I'm thinking in a good resolution? How can I do it?

Comment: try to change modification of your files, `sudo chmod 777 <filename>`.

Comment: The program would have to be _setuid_ to the system user, so that it will run with that user's privileges.

Comment: creating a user for a java app is not an unusual procedure, check for example this link http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-linux

Comment: so, it would be logical to run linux commands from within the program?
I don want the user to even be aware of the new user...